# Is there a way, in TypeScript, to deport inner builder class to an external file?

Tags: typescript, class, design-patterns, inner-classes, builder

In TypeScript, we can create builder class as an inner class of the class we want to build.

```ts
export class Car {
  brand: string;
  year: number;

  constructor(builder: Car) {
    this.brand = builder.brand;
    this.year = builder.year;
  }

  static Builder = class {
    brand = 'Ford';
    year = 2020;

    setBrand(brand: string) {
      this.brand = brand;
      return this;
    }

    setYear(year: number) {
      this.year = year;
      return this;
    }

    build() {
      return new Car(this);
    }
  };
}
```

In the above example, I have a Car class with an inner Builder to help me instantiate the Car object with:

`const car = new Car.Builder().setBrand('Fiat').setYear(2021).build();`

I would like to be able to export the definition of my Builder class outside object class (i.e., in the separate file) while keep the advantage of the inner static Builder.

Something like that:

```ts
export class Car {
  brand: string;
  year: number;

  constructor(builder: Car) {
    this.brand = builder.brand;
    this.year = builder.year;
  }

  static Builder = CarBuilder;
}

export class CarBuilder {
   brand = 'Ford';
   year = 2020;

   setBrand(brand: string) {
     this.brand = brand;
     return this;
   }

   setYear(year: number) {
     this.year = year;
     return this;
   }

   build() {
     return new Car(this);
   }
}
```

Alas this doesn't work and I cannot find a way to tell TypeScript to import an external class definition as in internal static class.
How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `Class 'CarBuilder' used before its declaration.` if you have the code in the order you have it.

If you change `CarBuilder` to be declared before `Car` (or if you import it from another file) you can use it

```
export class CarBuilder {
   brand = 'Ford';
   year = 2020;

   setBrand(brand: string) {
     this.brand = brand;
     return this;
   }

   setYear(year: number) {
     this.year = year;
     return this;
   }

   build() {
     return new Car(this);
   }
}

export class Car {
  brand: string;
  year: number;

  constructor(builder: Car) {
    this.brand = builder.brand;
    this.year = builder.year;
  }

  static Builder = CarBuilder;
}
```

after changing the order,

[image]

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEVQEICuAlkgCbBRwDeAUHPQEZQoB2pcAvHAOQBi0pbgG469AJ7BcnOACYADPJGi4aYDDzM2ACiatSALhUwoRFgHMAlNWX0YACyJoAdLrbTXpEfW9Q1BKCxw9o5e9AC%20NMqqMACaklBaEriGLAQAtgwUVrTetg7OSZRchaE%20fgFB%20aURygzEZFrZNnC%20MP6BLMAA7ti4WsFoFtU0NaCQsIioGL2UOXAehmjGpmahhSnpmVBK9AgQLEtQBAgw0Dr15FCGOFBNuQMumuxcdSSXj3qllY5Ohe4XFF%208VCNXoSxQMCICDghDeFGkN1hZAoIhqNycSMuNAA9Nj6AA9AD8kRoQA)

Comment: While I have the same error `... used before its declaration` if I switch the two classes (but this time on the CarBuilder class, the `static Builder = CarBuilder` line makes my program freeze. It seems that there is some infinite loop going on there... Could it be that reference Car in CarBuilder and then CarBuilder in Car is some cyclic code?

Comment: @DerekSvart Can you reproduce this on TS Playground? It works for me https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCcBCBXAliAJgUwdA3gFDQkBGCYAdptALzQDkAYgPYKYMDcxJAntojrQATAAYx3HtAjYALkgrUAFOSqYAXNNkI0lAOYBKAlJKyAFmggA6VdSG3M3Es4RyUCStHOWnJAL6EUjKyAJoCCEr8iJqUKAC2pLhGRM6mFtZRePSZvi5uHl7puQFSpOhYSskm0K6y7p6U2ADucIhK3hAGxYQloJAw8Hgp0A6aENq6er6ZMfGJCJIkwCyU4wgowLJsKuU4CJqDVakdNoo09GUYe6dquYWWVpn2u7iP4b4lJONgsmjA0KgrrghINAVhcNwSoMrGC9twAPTwkgAPQA-IFlqtZNBgIJ6I0WqCXhEDFZggo1EoAEQAFRYvBYsjAVNJwTCbTEAEYAByky4VLqETEQFggbBWEAsPRKXEIQVAA

Comment: Thanks @Samathingamajig. Your code works fine and it also works on my side as long as both classes are in the same file. I even checked that it worked by calling `new CarBuilder().` or `new Car.Builder()`. It is the case.
Alas, as soon as I put each class in separate files `car.ts` and `car-builder.ts`, the code freezes on my project (I don't know how to "simulate" multiple files in Playground to illustrate it).